# A fair coin is tossed four times. What is the probability...

Tags: probability

HW problem here. I know the answer is 6/16 (per the back of the book) but I can't figure out how they got that.

> A fair coin is tossed four times. What is the probability that the
>   number of heads appearing on the first two tosses is equal to the
>   number of heads appearing on the second two tosses?

My thought was that the probability of getting `x` heads on the first two throws would be $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$ and the same thing on the other side and then multiply the events together getting $\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{16}$

So where am I going wrong? How do they get the 6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3$ cases : either you have $0$ head appearing on the first two tosses, either you have $1$ or either you have $2$. You treated the case when you have $2$. The case when you have $0$ gives the same probability of $\frac{1}{16}$. The probability that the number of heads is $1$ on the first two tosses is $2 \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore you must add $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} = \frac{4}{16}$ to $\frac{2}{16}$.

Answer (score 1):

What are the possibilities that the number of heads on the first two tosses equals the number of heads on the second two tosses?  The possibilities are:  TTTT, HTHT, THHT, HTTH, THTH, HHHH.  So those are six possibilities.  There are 16 possibilities total.  So the answer is 6/16.

If the problem were different so that it had so many flips that it became annoying to write them all out individually you could (a) use a computer, or (b) calculate the probability of getting 0 heads in the first half and 0 heads in the second half, 1 head in the first half and 1 head in the second half, etc. And then find the probability of any of those events happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are clearly 16 different outcomes. If the equal number of heads is $0$, so both the first two and the last 2 have $0$ heads, we have all tails, which is 1 solution.

If both are 2, we have all heads, also 1 solution.

If both are one, each side separately has two options: TH, HT, independent of each other, which gives $2 \times 2 = 4$ solutions, altogether 6.

Answer (score 0):

For a generalization, suppose the coin has a probability $p$ of landing heads, and the outcome of individual tosses are independent and identically distributed.  For $n$ tosses, the number $X$ of heads observed is binomially distributed:  $X \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(n,p)$ with probability mass function $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}.$$  Then if we toss the coin $2n$ times, the probability that the number of heads in the first $n$ tosses equals the number of heads in the last $n$ tosses is simply $$\sum_{x=0}^n \biggl(\binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}\biggr)^2.$$  When $n = 2$, this simplifies to $$(1-p)^4 + 4p^2(1-p)^2 + p^4.$$  For $p = 1/2$, the sum is $$\frac{1}{4^n} \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x}^2.$$  For both $n = 2$ and $p = 1/2$, we get $$\frac{1}{16}(1 + 4 + 1) = \frac{6}{16} = \frac{3}{8}.$$